# Sign calculation in c++

Tags: c++, latitude-longitude

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude from degrees, minutes, seconds to a decimal degree number.  I have converted the numbers correctly but I am having troubles converting the sign.  When I input the numbers 39 57 21 for latitude and -75 11 14 for longitude, it converts correctly to (39.9558, 75.1872) but my sign calculation formula doesn't work properly.  I have checked over the code with a fine tooth comb but cannot seem to find an error in my formula.  The formula I was given to find this is: sign=(2x)/(abs(x)+1).  I have included my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int user_degrees_latitude, user_minutes_latitude, user_seconds_latitude,
        user_degrees_longitude, user_minutes_longitude, user_seconds_longitude,
        sign_latitude, sign_longitude;
    double total_minutes_latitude, total_degrees_latitude,
        total_minutes_longitude, total_degrees_longitude, final_latitude,
        final_longitude;
    const double sixtieth = (1. / 60);

    cout << "Input latitude in degrees, minutes, seconds:";
    cin >> user_degrees_latitude >> user_minutes_latitude >>
        user_seconds_latitude;

    cout << "Input longitude in degrees, minutes, seconds:";
    cin >> user_degrees_longitude >> user_minutes_longitude >>
        user_seconds_longitude;

    total_minutes_latitude =
        (user_minutes_latitude + ((sixtieth) * user_seconds_latitude));
    total_degrees_latitude =
        (abs(user_degrees_latitude) + ((sixtieth) * total_minutes_latitude));

    total_minutes_longitude =
        (user_minutes_longitude + ((sixtieth) * user_seconds_longitude));
    total_degrees_longitude =
        (abs(user_degrees_longitude) + ((sixtieth) * total_minutes_longitude));

    sign_latitude =
        (2 * (total_degrees_latitude)) / ((abs(total_degrees_latitude)) + 1);
    sign_longitude =
        (2 * (total_degrees_longitude)) / ((abs(total_degrees_longitude)) + 1);

    final_latitude = (sign_latitude * total_degrees_latitude);
    final_longitude = (sign_longitude * total_degrees_longitude);

    cout << user_degrees_latitude << " deg " << user_minutes_latitude << "\' "
         << user_seconds_latitude << "\" latitude, " << user_degrees_longitude
         << " deg " << user_minutes_longitude << "\' " << user_seconds_longitude
         << "\"";
    cout << " is (" << total_degrees_latitude << "," << total_degrees_longitude
         << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A short test case instead of all the code would be nice.

Comment: Well, maybe your formula is wrong?

Comment: This is basically the same code you posted earlier.  You will find that using your debugger will help you a lot more than asking SO to debug it for you.

Comment: You're computing the sign of `total_degrees_longitude`, which is computed via an absolute value.  It will always be positive, so of course the computed sign will always be positive.  Also, your sign formula is very strange, and wrong.  `sign(0.5) = 1/(abs(0.5)+1) = 0.66`???

Comment: `std::signbit()`, from `cmath`.

Answer (score 0):

First, try a better function for computing the sign, such as:

```
double sign(double x) {return (x < 0) ? -1 : 1;}
```

Secondly, since only the variables `user_degrees_latitude` and `user_degrees_longitude` are ever going to be negative, you should only use those to compute the sign at the end once you have the magnitudes.

```
sign_latitude  = sign(user_degrees_latitude);
sign_longitude = sign(user_degrees_longitude);
```